# Verificar se todos os elementos da lista são iguais

Tags: python, lista

Eu tenho uma lista de tempos contendo os valores de tempos de vários carros e eu gostaria de saber como faço para saber se todos esse valores são iguais

Eu pensei em comparar cada valor com o seu posterior, ou seja, comparar o valor de `tempos[i]` com o valor de `tempos[i+1]` e ir armazenando o resultado dessas comparações, ou seja, `True` ou `False` em uma outra lista qualquer e depois verificar se todos os elementos dessas outra lista são iguais a `True` ou não.

```
n = 4
tempos = [0.5, 1.3, 2.5, 3.4]

for i in range(0, len(tempos)):
    if(tempos[i] == tempos[i+1]):
       comparações.append(tempos[i] == tempos[i+1])
```

Mas sempre dá erro na linha: `if(tempos[i] == tempos[i+1])`

Comment: Seu vetor tem 4 posições que vão de 0 até 3, quando tu faz i+1, você está obtendo o valor seguinte, porém o que acontece você cai na última posição, e tenta buscar a posição 3+1, que não existe?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Uma forma que você pode fazer é o `set()`, onde quando uma lista é convertida para um set, elementos duplicados, são removidos, logo se os duplicados são removidos, o tamanho desse set é 1, o que implica que todos são iguais, senão, implica que existe valores diferentes na lista.

**Exemplo:**

```
tempos_diferentes = [0.5, 1.3, 2.5, 3.4]
tempos_iguais = [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]

len(set(tempos_iguais)) == 1
#Retorna True

len(set(tempos_diferentes)) == 1
#Retorna False
```

Answer (score 6):

### Uma solução SUPER simples

Transforme a lista em um `set`. Caso o tamanho do `set` gerado seja 1, então todos os item são iguais.

Exemplo

```
>>> l1 = [1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2]
>>> print(len(set(l1)) == 1)
False

>>> l2 = ["banana", "banana", "banana", "banana"]
>>> print(len(set(l2)) == 1)
True
```

### Outra solução

Gosto muito de usar o `Counter` da biblioteca `collections`.

O `Counter` conta os itens de um iterável e retorna um dicionário, onde a chave é o item e o valor é a quantidade. Veja abaixo

```
from collections import Counter

uma_lista = [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, "banana", 1, "banana"]

c = Counter(uma_lista)

print(c)
```

O resultado será:

```
Counter({1: 4, 2: 2, 'banana': 2})
```

Ou seja, 4 itens `1`, 2 itens `2` e 2 itens `banana`.

Vamos à sua pergunta

```
from collections import Counter

def todos_iguais(lista):
    c = Counter(lista)
    quantidade = list(c.values())[0]  # primeiro e talvez único valor da lista
    return quantidade == len(lista)  # se a quantidade for igual, todos os itens são iguais.
```

**Update** Claro que se a quantidade de itens na lista, ou seja `len(c.values())` for igual a 1, todos os itens são iguais.

Então, basta chamar a função, passando uma lista.

```
l1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 1]
print(todos_iguais(l1))    # o resultado será False
```

Perceba que esta solução, funciona para listas com outros tipos que não inteiro.

```
l2 = ["banana", "banana", "banana", "banana"]
print(todos_iguais(l2))   # o resultado será True
```

Espero ter ajudado

Comment: E ajudou, muito obrigado

Answer (score 3):

Você pode fazer uma função que verifica se o próximo número é igual ao atual, caso seja diferente já retorna logo que a lista não é totalmente igual(False), do contrario se o `for` for até o final da lista ele retorna (True).

Entradas:

```
tempos = [0.5, 1.3, 2.5, 3.4]
tempo1 = [1, 1, 1, 1]
tempo2 = [1, 1, 2, 2]
```

Função:

```
def verifica(lista):
    for i in range(len(lista) - 1): 
        # caso o próximo número seja diferente ja retornamos com False.
        if(lista[i] != lista[i + 1]): 
            return False 
    return True # caso chegue ao final da lista, retornamos True.
```

Saída:

```
verifica(tempos)
False

verifica(tempo1)
True

verifica(tempo2)
False
```

---

Sobre o seu código você não inicializou uma variável comparações. O erro de index se da pois você compara o elemento atual + 1, você tenta acessar ao final da iteração um elemento que não existe.

Corrigindo seu código ele ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
tempos = [0.5, 1.3, 2.5, 3.4]
comparacoes = []
for i in range(0, len(tempos) -1): 
    if(tempos[i] == tempos[i + 1]): 
        comparacoes.append(tempos[i])
```

Só que este código não faz o que você quer que ele faça. Seu código vai verificar se o elemento atual é igual ao próximo e se for igual ele adiciona a lista comparações, caso não seja igual ele não faz nada.

Answer (score 3):

O problema é que quando `i` chega no último elemento, `i + 1` tenta acessar um elemento que não existe. Então você só deveria ir até o penúltimo elemento.

Outro ponto é que não precisa criar outra lista com o resultado das comparações, para só depois ver se todos os resultados são `True`. Para verificar se todos os resultados são verdadeiros, basta usar [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all):

```
tempos = [0.5, 1.3, 2.5, 3.4]
todos_iguais = all(tempos[i] == tempos[i + 1] for i in range(len(tempos) - 1))
print(todos_iguais) # False
```

Vale lembrar que `all` retorna `True` se a lista for vazia. Se quer que retorne `False` para este caso, tem que tratar separadamente:

```
# retorna False se a lista for vazia (se não for vazia, usa o mesmo código anterior)
todos_iguais = not tempos or all(tempos[i] == tempos[i + 1] for i in range(len(tempos) - 1))
```

---

Mas como a ideia é saber se todos os elementos são iguais, tanto faz se você está comparando o elemento com o próximo ou com qualquer outro. Sendo assim, você poderia comparar todos com o primeiro:

```
# vê se a lista é vazia ou se todos são iguais ao primeiro
todos_iguais = not tempos or all(tempos[0] == x for x in tempos)
```

Agora é importante ver se a lista é vazia, senão dará erro ao tentar acessar o primeiro elemento.

Claro que será feita uma comparação inútil no início (o primeiro elemento será comparado com ele mesmo), mas se quiser pode fazer:

```
todos_iguais = not tempos or all(tempos[0] == x for x in tempos[1:])
```

Pois assim eu uso somente do segundo elemento em diante no `for`. Só não sei se vale a pena criar outra lista só para evitar uma comparação.

Repare também que em nenhum momento você precisa da variável `n`.

---

Outra alternativa - talvez meio *over engineered* - é usar [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby). Inclusive, na [própria documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) tem a "receita" para detectar se todos os elementos são iguais:

```
from itertools import groupby

tempos = [0.5, 1.3, 2.5, 3.4]
g = groupby(tempos)
todos_iguais = next(g, True) and not next(g, False)
```

A ideia é que `groupby` agrupa elementos consecutivos que são iguais em um único grupo. Ao chamar [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) a primeira vez, ele retorna o primeiro grupo. Se a lista só tiver elementos iguais, não existirá um segundo grupo, e portanto a segunda chamada de `next` retorna o segundo parâmetro informado, que no caso é `False` (ou seja, estou verificando se o primeiro grupo existe e se o segundo não existe, o que só ocorre se todos os elementos forem iguais).

Este código também retorna `True` para lista vazia. Se quiser que retorne `False` para este caso, basta mudar a primeira chamada para `next(g, False)`.

Answer (score 3):

Outra forma de resolver esta questão é utilizando função com auxílio da conversão de lista para set. Desta forma o código ficará:

```
def valores_iguais(lis):
    if len(set(lis)) == 1:
        return True
    return False


tempos = [0.5, 1.3, 2.5, 3.4]

print(valores_iguais(tempos))
```

Observe que este código envia a lista **tempos** como parâmetro para a função **valores_iguais()**. Chegando lá, o bloco `if` verificará se o tamanho da conversão da lista em sete é igual a **1**. Caso positivo, o retorno da função será **True** e, caso contrário, o retorno da função será **False**.

Se preferir pode utilizar a abordagem resultante da comparação entre o **tamanho da lista tempos** e a contagem de **algum** elemento da lista **tempo**. Desse modo podemos implementar o seguinte código:

```
def elementos_identicos(li):
    return True if len(li) == li.count(li[0]) else False


lista = [0.5, 1.3, 2.5, 3.4]

print(elementos_identicos(lista))
```

Neste código **lista** é passada como parâmetro para a função **elementos_identicos()**. A partir desse momento o retorno da função será **True** se o comprimento de **lista** for igual à contagem de qualquer um dos elementos da **lista**. Caso contrário o retorno será **False**.

Neste exemplo comparei **len(li)** com **li.count(li[0])**, ou seja, o tamanho da lista com a quantidade de elementos que possuem valor igual ao elemento de índice **0**.